# Install local package with the help of composer

Tags: composer-php

I want to install my local package using composer, I have tried solutions found from the web and didn't get desired results. Can anyone please give me steps for that?

Comment: This is possible if you are willing to push the package to a public or private repo. Do you have a Git or BitBucket account? It may be possible to do this locally, but I have never done that.

Comment: Would you edit your question to explain why you want to do this?